# LinkShare iTunes Affiliate links in an iOS app

Tags: iphone, itunes, affiliate

I have an app that aggregates apps from the app store for a specific audience, and I use the iTunes Affiliate program (via LinkShare).

When a user taps the download button, it opens safari with the affiliate link and redirects to the AppStore. That's how I see it happening in other apps as well ("Free App Tracker", for example).

However, while LinkShare counts the clicks, I don't see any "orders", and I know there should be a few.

The clicks count gets updated the same day, while the orders count didn't get updated at all (still 0) for 3 days now.

Do I need to call the url in any specific way? or do LinkShare take their time with orders reports?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LinkShare track the orders in different way: there is the transaction date which is the date when the purchase was done, and then there is the "process" date which is when the transaction has been processed by the LinkShare system. 
You can [read more about it](http://helpcenter.linkshare.com/publisher/questions.php?questionid=637).

Answer (score 0):

A few notes:

Are the purchases you that know happend via your link happen in the US store?
- The LinkShare program only support the US and CA programs so if the sale was made in another country you won't see any sales data.

iTunes advises that you wait three to five days for your sale to show up.  I've seen sales the next day and sometimes they take longer.  Typically, however, they are no later then a few days after you get the receipt for the sale.

You can call your link in a way that the redirects are processed in the background.  Check out this resource for details - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1629/_index.html

Hope that helps.